# Is it ok to format data inside a reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

If the payload is an array of object, is it ok to format the payload and write it into the redux store?

```
// example payload=[{name: "tim", age: 22}, ...]

const initialState = {
  userNames: [],
}
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { payload } = action

  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.USERS_SUCCESS: {
      return { ...state, userNames: payload.map(user => user.name) }
    }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question depends on how heavy formatting of the data your are doing. You can do small formatting operations such as merging arrays, merging objects etc but certainly not the looping through all the array and finding certain keys etc.

> The downside of doing array map or filter in the reducers, will
>   significantly reduce the performance of the app depending on the data.
>   Do all heavy data operations outside the reducers and then update the
>   state. Bulky reducers are error porn and may create problems which are
>   difficult to find.

Hope this helps.